# Doctrine Update by DQL + field with parenthesis: "(" and ")"

Tags: php, doctrine

I have a doctrine update query to save my data:

> $customer = Doctrine_Query::create()
>
> ->update('Customer')
>
> ->set('fax',"'". $this->getRequest()->getParam('fax')."'")
>
> ->where('id ='.$this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
>
> ->execute();

The problem is that the field fax has parenthesis and doctrine returns an error in the query because of these parenthesis "(" and ")".

Somebody knows a solution for this?
Thank's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$customer = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('Customer')
    ->set('fax', '?', $this->getRequest()->getParam('fax'))
    ->where('id = ?', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
    ->execute();
```

Comment: This. Always use "?" (or another binding method) to take advantage of PDO's escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Doctrine, but what if you escape the parenthesis?

```
$fax = $this->getRequest()->getParam('fax');
$fax = str_replace(array('(',')'), array('\(','\)'), $fax);

// ...
->set('fax',"'". $fax ."'");
```

Edit, and it might also be good to sanitize the input to only include numbers, parenthesis and maybe dashes:

```
// replace everything not 0-9, (, ) or - with nothing
$fax = preg_replace('/[^0-9\(\)\-]/','',$fax);
```

Comment: Thanks by the comment. i could do something like this, but i would like to solve it without this, with some solution in doctrine..The first answer worked...